How to simplify this ternary expression?
I wonder if there is a simpler way to write this, or is it already in it's most basic form?
A ? (B && C) : B


The word "simple" is doing a lot of work here. If you want another human being to understand your code in a year, plain if statements would be "simpler" in that sense.

This could be restructured as (A && B) ? C : B, but that isn't necessarily 'simpler'

The way it is now is pretty simple and easy to understand, you could remove the ternary  like A && B && C || B?

Follow up clarification question: do you just want a truthy vs falsy result, or are you actually looking for the value of either B or C depending on the truthiness of A B and C? The full context is not clear in the given code snippet.

Could you [edit] to make it explicit what counts as "simplifying" here? And also maybe make it a [mre] by defining A, B, and C? Are they variables or do they stand for arbitrary expressions (the concern is whether changing evaluation order or number of times has any observable effects, which could happen for arbitrary expressions, or possibly even for pathologically defined global variables).

This all boils down to what you mean by "simpler". Normally I don't recommend ChatGPT for answers but this would seem to be a good question for it (spoiler alert -- it thinks it's already as simple as possible)

drawing a kmap you can get B && (!A + C)

Another thing that may be of GREAT importance here is the consideration of side-effects in the different parts of the predicate. In this case, I'm not sure I can think of a "bad" thing (because B appears twice already), but that's an important consideration.

Assuming all are booleans, it says that to return true, either A and B and C must be true, or A must be false and B must be true (with C irrelevant). This can be written as A && B && C || !A && B.
From this we can see that the result can only be true if B is true, so we can extract B from both parts: B && (A && C || !A) or the equivalent B && (!A || A && C).
This can be further reduced to B && (!A || C). We now have one less term: A, B and C each occur once, so it could be considered simpler. Although because of the negation, not everyone might find it simpler to understand.
Truth tables (created using https://truth-table.com):


or B && (!A + C) which i got after solving a kmap :D

since 'B' will execute in either case, why not do it this way:
B          //Execute B.
A && C     //If A is true, execute C else do nothing.


You're assuming that A, B and C are callables to be executed.  The question is missing important context.
